# Is it best to write a JSON-LD script for each date that an event is on or define all dates in one script?

Tags: schema, json-ld, structured-data

**Goal:**
I want to add schema markup to events on my site.
I have a website that sells event tickets from June - September.
Every Friday, there is a pool party (see all dates at the end of this post)

**Question:**
Is it best to write a script for each date that the event is on, for example:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
...
"startDate": "2020-06-06T17:00",
...
}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
...
"startDate": "2020-06-13T17:00",
...
}
</script>
```

Or, is there a way to define all dates that this event is on in the same script, for example:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
...
"startDate": "2020-06-06T17:00",
"startDate": "2020-06-13T17:00",
...
}
</script>
```

**All dates this event is on:**
Friday, June 7, 2019
Friday, June 14, 2019
Friday, June 21, 2019
Friday, June 28, 2019
Friday, July 5, 2019
Friday, July 12, 2019
Friday, July 19, 2019
Friday, July 26, 2019
Friday, August 2, 2019
Friday, August 9, 2019
Friday, August 16, 2019
Friday, August 23, 2019
Friday, August 30, 2019

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer from a Google perspective. 
In the guide **[Get your event on Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event?hl=en#technical-guidelines)**, speaks directly about this:

> Each event MUST have a unique URL (a leaf page) and markup on that
>   URL.
>
> Currently, the event experience on Google only supports pages that
>   focus on a single event. We recommend focusing on adding markup to
>   your event posting pages instead of pages that list schedules or
>   multiple events.

Therefore, if you want to get **[rich results of Google](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/09/making-review-rich-results-more-helpful.html)**, then you **SHOULD** create a separate web page for each event. Accordingly, each web page should have structured data for only one event and one date.